# Getting this weird errors from apple. Everything was fine yesterday

Tags: ios, iphone

2 weeks ago I started trying to fix my apps's so that they can be released with Apple. At the time the app worked perfectly. Before starting XCode this morning, i started the emulator and noticed my app worked perfectly. I then proceeded to open Xcode and all I did was change ! thing, and now nothing works.

I'm an amateur, so a lot of the things that come natural to you seem like stupid questions from me.

I'm not sure how top decode assembly language. Can some one help me figure out what's going on. This function here show's where the problem is. it say's "local declaration 'soundfilePath' hides instance variable" & "local declaration 'soundfileURL' hides instance variable"

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    playButton.enabled = NO;
    stopButton.enabled = NO;

    NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDir;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary 
                                    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], 
                                    AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], 
                                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], 
                                    AVSampleRateKey,
                                    nil];

    NSError *error = nil;

    audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                     initWithURL:soundFileURL
                     settings:recordSettings
                     error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
    }




    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

this here is some of the assembly error message i'm getting.

0x02622a4f  <+0011>  mov    0x8(%ebp),%esi

Comment: you have a global (probably a property) definition of `soundFileURl` and `soundFilePath` , but in `viewDidLoad` you declared local variables with the same names. If that has to do with the assembly error, I doubt.

Answer (score 2):

> "local declaration 'soundfilePath' hides instance variable" & "local declaration 'soundfileURL' hides instance variable"

That means you have declared an instance variable (either inside the braces at the top of your .m file, or in your header file) with the same name as a local variable. You have these lines:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
                           stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
```

Elsewhere in the file, you will also have these lines:

```
NSString *soundFilePath;
NSURL *soundFileURL;
```

Using them both is not a good idea.

Either rename the local variables, or use the instance variables. If you use those variables elsewhere in your class, use the instance variables:

```
soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have properties called `soundFilePath` and `soundFileURL` already, and when you declare those local variables in the method that you've shown above, you are "shadowing" them. That is, your local variable is used in preference to the property, and this is messing up your code.

The fix is one of two things:

Change the name of the local variables

or

If you have lines in your code that `@synthesise` your properties, remove them. Modern Xcode auto-synthesises property stores, and with the benefit of prepending a `_` in front of them, so your property variables will be `_soundFilePath` and `_soundFileURL` and you won't be shadowing them anymore.